# Network configuration between nginx server (running on WSL) and Beeware app (Build and run from windows anaconda)

Tags: sockets, anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux, local-network, webdev.webserver

my web server is on wsl, and beeware is on anaconda (windows version not linux), how do I configure beeware app to communicate with wsl server.
is there a feasible way?
current I'm using ngrok host as a gateway.
Is there any alternate way that doesn't require data packet to travel outside my system
Is there any guide to develop a local system?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to attempt to answer this generically since I don't currently use Beeware/Anaconda.  I tried skimming the Beeware docs, but too much of it (including the "publish", which might be a key element in the nginx integration) is "Coming soon".

Assuming there are no virtual machines or containers in the mix, Windows *should* detect ports on the WSL2 instance and map them correctly to localhost.  For instance, if in WSL you `python3 -m http.server 3000`, then you should be able to open that page in a Windows web browser at http://localhost:3000.  So, by default, Anaconda on Windows *should* be able to access your web server in WSL through localhost.  If this isn't happening:

- First, make sure that nginx is listening on 0.0.0.0
- Sometimes the Windows localhost auto-mapping seems to break.  See this answer for some additional ideas.  A quick-fix is often to just do a `wsl --shutdown` to reset the interfaces.  A longer-term fix might be to disable Windows Fast Startup.

On the flip side, if there is any connection from nginx that needs to be made to Beeware/Anaconda, WSL2 does *not* map localhost back to the Windows host.  You'll need to access it by the Windows host IP.

The easiest method is using mDNS, meaning from within WSL2 you can access the Windows host at the mDNS name "*mycomputername*.local", where *mycomputername* is the Windows "computer name".

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65634105/11810933) for more details and alternatives if mDNS doesn't work.