# golang connection postgres tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused

Tags: postgresql, go

I've problem with connecting my pgadmin database (postgres) with golang.
I got tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused on ubuntu wsl but on windows powershell command is connecting me normally. Unfortunetlly even on powershell I have problems with puting anything via postman or using GET

This is how my code looks like.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

type Storage interface {
    CreateAccount(*Account) error
    DeleteAccount(int) error
    UpdateAccount(*Account) error
    GetAccountByID(int) (*Account, error)
}

type PostgresStore struct {
    db *sql.DB
}

func NewPostgresStore() (*PostgresStore, error) {
    connStr := "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=sharefiles user=postgres password=root sslmode=disable "
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if err := db.Ping(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &PostgresStore{
        db: db,
    },nil
}

func (s *PostgresStore) Init() error {
    return s.createAccountTable()
}

func (s *PostgresStore) createAccountTable() error {
    query := `create table if not exists account (
        id serial primary key,
        first_name varchar(50),
        last varchar(50),
        create_at timestamp
    )`

    _, err := s.db.Exec(query)
    return err
}

func (s *PostgresStore) CreateAccount(acc *Account) error {
    
    query := `insert into account
    (first_name, last_name, created_at)
    values ($1, 2$, $3)`
    resp,err := s.db.Query(
        query,
        acc.FirstName,
        acc.LastName,
        acc.CreatedAt)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", resp)

    return nil
}

func (s *PostgresStore) UpdateAccount(*Account) error {
    return nil
}

func (s *PostgresStore) DeleteAccount(id int) error {
    return nil
}

func (s *PostgresStore) GetAccountByID(id int) (*Account, error) {
    return nil, nil
}
```

I was trying to switch do docker, hovewer problems are the same. Can't get connection with DB.

Comment: can you share with us where your database is running?  Your golang code shoes `host=localhost` so I am assuming you have set up postgres on your Ubuntu machine?  We may need to also look at how your Postgres is configured (is `listen_addresses` set correctly?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WSL2 use "localhost" to access Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65625762/wsl2-use-localhost-to-access-windows-service)

Comment: Have you tried connecting to your database with `psql` or some other client? The error certainly implies the issue is not a programming problem but the server isn't running or isn't listening on that address/port.